# ASP.NET DLL Partial Binding Error

Tags: asp.net, binding, partial

I am running into the following error when running my ASP.NET application.  I am running this using IIS 6.0 on WinXP 64.  The assembly is signed and thus needs a strong name, but apart from adding a reference and using the functions in the dll, I don't know how to resolve the error.  I have tried installing the assembly in the GAC, but that did not help.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = random
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: random.dll | Domain ID: 10
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Root/Server/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Root\Server\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Root\Server\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/server/aeb22d03/3a6c0025/random.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/server/aeb22d03/3a6c0025/random/random.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Root/Server/bin/random.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by enabling .NET v4.0 64 bit ISAPI extensions.  The 32 bit extensions were enabled by default.